# Get the index of Array List

Tags: c#

I have a question to Array List in C#

I have an Array with the following elements:

```
- LQI Request
- 0123456
- LQI Request
- 456789
- LQI Request
- 6789
.....
```

Now all I want to do is, find the strings with `LQI Request`, and then get the string next to it, that's what I've tried so far:(index is a global variable)

```
if(myString.Contains("LQI"))
            {
                index= stored_data.IndexOf(myString);
            }
MessageBox.Show(index.ToString());
MessageBox.Show(stored_data[index+1].Tostring());
```

verytime i run this code, the index stays the same. IT should be: 0,2,4

Please help

Comment: Try  this http://www.dotnetperls.com/arraylist

Comment: You could use: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/01h9de4t(v=vs.110).aspx 
index= Array.IndexOf(stored_data, “value”, index);
index++;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
List<string> data = new List<string>
{
    "- LQI Request",
    "- 0123456",
    "- LQI Request",
    "- 456789",
    "- LQI Request",
    "- 6789"
};

var result = data.Select((x, i) => // x is the element, i is the index
                        {
                            if (x.Contains("LQI"))
                                if(i + 1 < data.Count) // is the index inside the bounds of the array
                                    return data[i + 1].Substring(2); // don't take the "- "
                            return string.Empty;
                        }).Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x)) // ignore empty results
                          .ToArray();

// result: ["0123456", "456789", "6789"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like below does what you are describing.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        List<String> stored_data = new List<String>() { "LQI REquest","-0123456", "LQI Request", "-456789", "LQI Request", "-6789", "non valid", "12345", "extra", "12354" };
        for (int j=0; j< stored_data.Count; j++)
        {

            if (stored_data[j].Contains("LQI"))
            {

                Console.Write((j).ToString()+ ": ");
                var temp = j + 1;
                Console.Write(stored_data[temp]);
                Console.WriteLine();
            }

        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```